# How to handle convertion on columns.Bound?

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-grid, converters, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have this Method for the ActionResult for the grid I want to show:

```
    public ActionResult ReadTransactions([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var userInfo = new UserInfo(User.Identity);

        using (var ctx = new KassenautomatEntities())
        {
            var transactions = ctx.Protokoll.Where(e => e.KartenID == userInfo.CardId);
            var result = transactions.ToDataSourceResult(request);
            return Json(result);
        }
    }
```

And this is my View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<WebInterface.Models.Protokoll>()
    .Name("Transactions")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.Datum).Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}");
        columns.Bound(o => o.TransaktionTyp);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Betrag);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Client);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(10)
        .Read(read => read.Action("ReadTransactions", "Transactions"))
     )
)
```

The problem I have is with this line of the view:

```
columns.Bound(o => o.TransaktionTyp);
```

`TransaktionTyp` is an integer, which references to a specific string I want to show here. So I have developed the following enum for it:

```
    public enum TransactionType
    {
        Charged = 0,
        Debited = 1,
        CardBlocked = 2,
        CardEstablished = 3,
        ProtocolError = 4,
        PackageError = 5,
        CardCanceled = 6,
        CardFree = 7
    }
```

And to resolve this, I have the following Method:

```
    public static string TransactionTypeToDisplayName(TransactionType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case TransactionType.Charged:
                return "Aufgeladen";
            case TransactionType.Debited:
                return "Abgebucht";
            case TransactionType.CardBlocked:
                return "Karte gesperrt";
            case TransactionType.CardEstablished:
                return "Karte eingerichtet";
            case TransactionType.ProtocolError:
                return "Protokoll Fehler";
            case TransactionType.PackageError:
                return "Paket Fehler";
            case TransactionType.CardCanceled:
                return "Karte Storno";
            case TransactionType.CardFree:
                return "Karte Gratisabgabe";
            default:
                return "Unbekannte Transaktionstyp";
        }
    }
```

My problem is, how can I format my column using my `TransactionTypeToDisplayName` method?

What I want to, is something like that:

```
columns.Bound(o => TransactionTypeToDisplayName(o.TransaktionTyp))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, not exactly that what I wanted, but this is finaly my solution:

First I have written an extension Method:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent;

namespace WebInterface.Core.Extension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Erweiterungsmethoden für das KendoGrid
    /// </summary>
    public static class KendoGrid
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Fügt der Tabelle eine Bindung mit einem Enum zu
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TModel">Der Typ des Models</typeparam>
        /// <typeparam name="TEnum">Der Typ der Enumeration</typeparam>
        /// <param name="model">Das Model</param>
        /// <param name="expression">Die Expression</param>
        public static void Bound<TModel, TEnum>(this GridColumnFactory<TModel> model, Expression<Func<TModel, byte?>> expression)
            where TModel : class
            where TEnum : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
        {
            //Sicherstellen, dass es sich um einen Enum handelt
            if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");
            }

            //Die einzelnen Werte des Enums extrahieren
            var values = (TEnum[])System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum));

            //Eine Zuweisungsliste von Wert und Anzeigenamen erstellen
            var selectList = new SelectList(values.Select(value => new
            {
                value = Convert.ToInt32(value),
                displayName =
                    value.GetType()
                        .GetMember(value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                        .First()
                        .GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()
                        .Name
            }), "value", "displayName");

            //Fügt die Spalte hinzu
            model.ForeignKey(expression, selectList);
        }
    }
}
```

The second Part was rewriting the enumeration with Display Attributes:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebInterface.Core.Enum
{
    public class Transaction
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Die Transaktionstypen
        /// </summary>
        public enum Type
        {
            [Display(Name = "Aufgeladen")]
            Charged = 0,

            [Display(Name = "Abgebucht")]
            Debited = 1,

            [Display(Name = "Karte Gesperrt")]
            CardBlocked = 2,

            [Display(Name = "Karte Eingerichtet")]
            CardEstablished = 3,

            [Display(Name = "Protokoll Fehler")]
            ProtocolError = 4,

            [Display(Name = "Paket Fehler")]
            PackageError = 5,

            [Display(Name = "Karte Storno")]
            CardCanceled = 6,

            [Display(Name = "Karte Gratisabgabe")]
            CardFree = 7
        }

    }
}
```

To bind it, we have to call it this way:

```
columns.Bound<Protokoll, Transaction.Type>(o => o.TransaktionTyp);
```

`Protokoll` is the Model from the Entity Framework, `Transaction.Type` is the Enumeration.